# Audio/Video Conferencing Application in Android

Tags: android, chat, sip

I have to develop an application in android for audio/video conferencing. Which is the most efficient way of implementing this? While my research, I came across Android's SIP API. Can it be used for implementing the audio as well as video conferencing ? And If yes, what shall I use to stream the videos in real time? Shall I use any RTSP library for this?

Please Guide me.

Thanks,
Rupesh

Answer (score 0):

Okz for my practical project i used Spydroid which use `rtsp` protocol sdp less. you can customize it for audio use only. i will prefer spydroid because it uses pure java in which it reads `camera packets` and right them to linux socket and read them from there by `rtsp` server.

on other hand if i am not wrong sip uses `c/c++` codes too